# "Back to top" with mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

Can anyone give me a similar script for mootools. I'm using jquery and I need a similar function like this to use with mootools:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if( $(".page").height() < $(window).height() ) {
       $(".backtop").hide();
   }
   else {
       $(".backtop").show();
   }
});
```

What I want is a "back to top" button that only appears when the div.page is bigger than the screen window.

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-watermark

Comment: how about the scrollSpy - http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-scrollspy

Answer (score 2):

```
$$('a.backtop').setStyle('display',
    document.getElement('div.page').getSize().y > window.getSize().y ? 'block' : 'none'
);
```

note sometimes on old ie you might have to wrap $(window) or $(document).

http://jsfiddle.net/wD6RY/

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
   ($('div.page')> window.getSize().y) ? $('div.backtop').fade(1) : $('div.backtop').fade(0)  
});
```

Comment: Be aware that .fade is a shortcut and is not part of MooTools Core. It seem as you wanted to write $$ instead of $ and since $$ is returning a collection you have to do $$('.css-selector')[0]. also you are comparing and element `$('div.page') > window.getSize().y` with the window height, which will be always false. So you probably forgot to call .getSize().y on $$('div.page')[0].